# ng-file-upload unable to get the file data in angular controller and also in server side PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, ng-file-upload

This is my form with ng-file-upload,

```
<form ng-submit="form.$valid && picture(user)" name="form" novalidate class="form-horizontal">
    <input 
        name="name" 
        ng-model="user.name" 
        type="text" 
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Name" 
        ng-required="true" 
    />
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input 
            type="file" 
            ngf-select 
            ng-model="user.profile" 
            name="profile"    
                accept="image/*" 
                ngf-max-size="10MB" 
                required
                ngf-model-invalid="errorFile"
            />
            <span class="erra" ng-show="form.profile.$error.required">*required</span><br>
            <span class="erra" ng-show="form.profile.$error.maxSize">File too large 
            {[{errorFile.size / 1000000|number:1}]}MB: max 2M</span>
            <img 
                width="150" 
                ng-show="form.profile.$valid" 
                ngf-thumbnail="user.profile" 
                class="thumb"
            />
            <button ng-click="user.profile = null" ng-show="user.profile">Remove</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my js

```
Ajax.post('/register', user)            // Ajax is my custom factory it is working
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error.data.message);
    });
```

To process at my backend(PHP) when I query it, there is only empty array and no file contents received. What could be the problem?

Comment: Why aren't you using `$http.post`?

Comment: @developer033 Yes I use $http.post not directly but indirectly through factory